# How to get a filename from the download URL who dosen't have a filename inside the link

Tags: python, http, https, request, bots

Hi i'm codding a bot in python
to the zoom download api, but
but now i'm going through this. I need to know the name of the file I am downloading through that URL, but inside the URL it does not contain the name of the file. It is just downloaded automatically through it.

Ex of an download URL:

https://zztop.us/rec/download/6cUsf-r5pjo3GNfGtgSDAv9xIXbzy9vms0iRKq6YNn0m8UHILNlKiMrMWMecDkmKyv5o675Hp1ZrKPF16

How can i code in python a way to know the filename being downloaded ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

with the help of Mostafa Labib I managed to get where I wanted, here is the code working for those who want to know the filename of a file downloaded by download_url  of zoom

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from os.path import basename
url="https://zztop.us/rec/download/6cUsfr5pjo3GNfGtgSDAv9xIXbzy9vms0iRKq6YNn0m8UHILNlKiMrMWMecDkmKyv5o675Hp1ZrKPF16"
token = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
url = (url + token)
response = urlopen(url)
arq_name = basename(response.url)
arq, tsh = arq_name.split("?", 1)
print(arq)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use urllib to parse the link then get the filename from the headers.

```
from urllib.request import urlopen 
url = "https://zztop.us/rec/download/6cUsf-r5pjo3GNfGtgSDAv9xIXbzy9vms0iRKq6YNn0m8UHILNlKiMrMWMecDkmKyv5o675Hp1ZrKPF16"
response = urlopen(url)
filename = response.headers.get_filename()
print(filename)
```

Comment: Hi Mostafa, I already tried it, it returns me "None"


I don't know if there is a relationship but you have to be logged into the account in the browser for the link to work, is there any way to put this in code?

Comment: I think you need to add access token to the link like this: `url = url +'?access_token=' + zoom_access_token` to get the access token follow the answer in this [link](https://devforum.zoom.us/t/requesting-access-token-via-python/6637)

Comment: Now it is returning me "none". I tested the link in the browser and is downloading normally with acess_token in the url

Comment: Mostafa, thank you. I improved your code, and get the correct response. Thanks for the help